# Only the video that is clicked on should play

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

**To reproduce issue:** Click on one play button, and the video loads.

Then Click on the **X**

Now click on a different play button and you will see, the video that was clicked on before is now playing, along with the video I just clicked on. So now there are 2 videos playing at the same time.

To test code, press **Run**, not update: https://jsitor.com/l_crlisuws

What would need to be adjusted in the code to fix that?

How is that fixed in the code?

```
function createStopHandler(player) {
    const stopButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    stopButtons.forEach(function stopButtonHandler(buttons) {
      buttons.addEventListener("click", function buttonClickHandler() {
        player.stopVideo();
      });
    });
  }

  function createPlayHandler(player) {
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".thePlay");
    playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(buttons) {
      buttons.addEventListener("click", function buttonClickHandler() {
        player.playVideo();
      });
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
    createStopHandler(player);
    createPlayHandler(player);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all the players and check if any of them is already playing and then stop them.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {        
        var temp = event.target.getVideoUrl();
        var tempPlayers = $("iframe.yt_players");
        for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            if (players[i].getVideoUrl() != temp)
                players[i].stopVideo();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the link for js fiddle
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8P7y/82/)

Comment: How does this fix the problem in the post - the fiddle requires all three videos to be on display at once to use their separate start buttons, which is not the case in the posted code (which is designed to have at most one video on display, and then only when it is playing?

Comment: Yes you are right only one player is displayed but at the back 3 separate players are created.
This code is from this post question
`function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  managePlayer.add(".playa", {});
  managePlayer.add(".playb", {
    playerVars: {
      playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
    }
  });
  managePlayer.add(".playc", {});
  manageCover.init({
    container: ".container",
    playButton: ".thePlay"
  });
  manageUI.init({});
}
`

Answer (score 0):

The stop button handlers are created and added in

```
  function createStopHandler(player) {
    const stopButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    stopButtons.forEach(function stopButtonHandler(buttons) {
      buttons.addEventListener("click", function buttonClickHandler() {
        player.stopVideo();
      });
    });
  }
```

Assuming `createStopHandle` is called for each of the three players, each `exit` button will have three click handlers, where each handler stops one video. Clicking an exit button will attempt to stop some videos that aren't playing but this should not have any unwanted side effects.

The play button handlers are created and added in

```
 function createPlayHandler(player) {
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".thePlay");
    playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(buttons) {
      buttons.addEventListener("click", function buttonClickHandler() {
        player.playVideo();
      });
    });
  }
```

Now there are now three  `thePlay` class buttons, so the `forEach` loop adds a handler to **every** button to play the player provided in the argument. So clicking a play button can start multiple videos, but it should only start one.

The solution is to only add a listener to a play button to play the one video, which I will leave to you to devise the workings thereof: the button needs a means of identifying the player it belongs to but (almost) nothing has been set up for that purpose.

---

Note - adding event listeners *seems* to occur when a play button is clicked and may be (is?) allowing the same event listener to be added multiple times. After fixing the handlers so that each button only ever starts one video, make sure the button only has one handler to play its video, as opposed to multiple event handlers to start the same video.

---

Edit: **TLDR;**

Clicking a start button is handled by `coverClickHandler` which calls `createPlayer` which calls `videoPlayer.addPlayer` which creates a new YT player, which when ready calls `onPlayerReady` which calls `createStopHandler` and `createPlayHandler`.

So every start click creates a new player, without deleting previous players for the same video, with no removal of event handlers that no longer make sense to call, and with no selection of the correct player to start when a start button is clicked.

This needs redesign. I wish you the best with the repairs!

Comment: I was told this in another answer: "You need to get all the players and check if any of them is already playing and then stop them." Is that all I need to do, or no?

Comment: Clicking a play button starts all videos that have been previously played - the stop button works and no video is playing when the play buttons are on display. Starting videos other than the one the play button is supposed to start is the bug that needs to be fixed. The other answer appears to stop all players when anyone of them fires an event that it has actually started playing - which works because the standard play buttons don't start multiple videos. If you don't want the svg buttons you could use it, but it doesn't fix your bug.

Comment: Actually if you run the other fiddle, it presents all three videos at once.

Comment: Which is different from how this code is set up: https://jsitor.com/l_crlisuws // That is what you are saying.

Comment: You mean this I think:

Clicking a play button starts all videos that have been previously played - the stop button works and no video is playing when the play buttons are on display. 
Starting videos other than the one play button that was previously clicked is supposed to start, and the other videos are supposed to be stopped.
 That is the bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Yes I can agree with that. Clicking one of the play buttons when videos are stopped should only start one video, not multiple videos.